# having problems with mysql statement where and or based on user input

Tags: mysql

```
$query = "SELECT username, email, password, salt 
          FROM tbl_memembers 
          WHERE (username = $resetuser) OR (email = $resetuser)";
```

This keeps returning that there is nothing in the database, when I know for a fact that there is matching those details entered ($resetuser = $_POST from previous page)

Comment: `username = '$resetuser'  email = '$resetuser'`

Comment: Knew it was something little, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try with this query

```
 $query = "SELECT username, email, password, salt 
          FROM tbl_memembers 
          WHERE username = '$resetuser'  email = '$resetuser' ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a table namned `'tbl_memembers'` or should it be `'tbl_members'`? As @Abhik Chakraborty points out - the parameters should be surrounded by ''. Then again - shouldn't '' just declare $resetuser as a string, not the parameter name? I'm a .NET-developer and have no experience of PHP but in .NET any parameter must be surrounded by `username = '" & parametername & "'`.